# How to replace or ignore the Accented characters in SSIS

Tags: xslt, ssis, special-characters, script-task

I have a SSIS package which reads the input file first & then validate it and then process the same. The validation is being carried through Script Task.

When the file is processed i am getting an error "invalid character in the given encoding". When verified i identified that this is due to the Accented character present in the file **first name: André**.

I tried replacing these characters in the xslt file using the **replace(normalize-unicode())** function but its not working because the script task is being called initially.

Can anyone help me in ignoring/replacing these special character while processing the file?

Comment: I'd suggest that you should use UTF-7 encoding while importing data into your staging table.

Answer (score 0):

In a dataflow task you can replace values using the applicable unicode hex value. The following code replaces three common accent marks with a blank space:

(DT_STR,500,1252)TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([YOUR_FIELD],"\x0060",""),"\x00B4",""),"\x02CB",""))

Find more here: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/